# Pass the current doc id to detailsPage

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to fetch data from a firestore documents where these document contain sub-collection.

user should get details of the listTile on tapping in new page. the thing is I have problem passing the doc id on tapping.

```
  body: StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('myMainCollection').snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
      return FirestoreListView(documents: snapshot.data.documents);
    },
 child: ListView.builder(

        itemCount: documents.length,
        itemExtent: 90.0,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {


          final myListTile = ListTile(

              onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => detailCard(documents[index] ),
      ),
    );
  },
```

on the detailPage i have this code:

```
 body: StreamBuilder(

    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('myMainCollection').document("TappedDocID").collection('sub-collection').snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
      return FirestoreListView(documents: snapshot.data.documents);
    },
  ),
```

any idea how to pass the doc id the user taps on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is pass the id in the details page and then in details page fetch the data using the id you passed.

I'm passing and retrieving the same way and it's working for me..

**Example:**

**Pass doc id from list page to details page using navigator:**

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => DetailsPage(
      docId: 'theIdYouWantToPass',
    ),
  ),
);
```

**In details page:**

```
class DetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String docId;

  DetailsPage(
      {Key key, @required this.docId})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  DetailsPageState createState() {
    return new DetailsPageState();
  }
}

// accessing the doc id in details page like this
class DetailsPageState
    extends State<DetailsPage> {
  // example if you want to store it in another var
  // or you can directly use **this.widget.docId**
  var docId = this.widget.docId;
}
```