# Flutter - pass data between widgets

Tags: dart, flutter

I have 2 widgets:

1. ReportList
2. ReportDetail

I'm trying to pass the report data from my RepostList Widget to my ReportDetail widget, and make another API call to get more info about the report in my ReportDetail widget.

In my ReportList the navigation works like this:

```
onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
                          return new ReportDetail(reports[i]);
                        }));
                      },
```

My ReportDetail class:

```
class ReportDetail extends StatefulWidget {

  final report;

  ReportDetail({Key key, @required this.report}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ReportDetailState createState() {
    return new ReportDetailState();
  }
}

class ReportDetailState extends State<ReportDetail> {

  var report;

  Color mainColor = const Color(0xff3C3261);

  void getData() async {
    debugPrint(this.report);
    var report = await getReport(this.report['id']);

    setState(() {
      this.report = report;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getData();

    if (this.report == null) {
      debugPrint(this.report);
      return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Loading..."),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      var list = (report['items'] as List)
          .map((item) =>
          TableRow(children: [
            Text(item['id'].toString()),
            Text(item['report_id'].toString()),
            Text(item['place'])
          ]))
          .toList();
      list.insert(
          0,
          TableRow(children: [
            Text("R1"),
            Text("R2"),
            Text("R3"),
          ]));
      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text(report['name'])),
          body: Container(child: Table(children: list)));
    }
  }
}
```

I have 2 issues:

1. I get the following error in my ReportList:

   Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
2. In the ReportDetail widget, How I can make sure I have the data from my API (the request has finished and this.report is now with data) before creating the table?

Comment: remove return keyword from "Navigator.push()" like 
onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new ReportDetail(reports[i])));
              },

Comment: If you have 2 issues the better is open 2 questions, no?
1 - In the onPressed you pass array "reports" but I can't find it in the code of ReportDetail class.

Comment: check out this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54859582/pass-the-current-doc-id-to-detailspage/54859743#54859743

Comment: @AmitJangid Thanks, it was exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass the current doc id to detailsPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54859582/pass-the-current-doc-id-to-detailspage)